# Grouping Points in Time

Tags: python, time, time-series, grouping

I have a series of points in time, say about ~60 events over the course of an hour. I'd like to figure out how to segment this series into "sub-series" based on how close in time the events occur.

The thing is, I am extremely hesitant to define an arbitrary interval to split on; i.e., I don't want to say, let's group events at every ten minutes. In the same way, I'm hesitant to define a "break threshold"; I don't want to say, if five minutes has passed without an event, start a new segment.

(For the record, the events have no inherent value for the purposes of this grouping. It's simply a series of points in time.)

Is there any way to dynamically segment a time series? I researched a few different things, and the most promising line of investigation was into Bayesian blocking, but I couldn't determine a way to modify it into what I need.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by grouping events this way? How can you tell if a set of events should count as a sub-series?

Comment: If you know how many sub-series you want, K-means clustering is great.  If you have a quality metric for a given segmentation, repeated K-means clustering with different numbers of clusters lets you optimize that metric.  But you do need *some* idea like this as a starting point!-)

Comment: Hmm, well the points represent points in time at which something is said, and I'm trying to group them into subdialogues. So I won't know how many clusters I'll have.

I've been thinking about what sort of quality metric I could use for this, but I haven't been able to figure out what would work for this. (Note: I'm not concerned about the subdialogues being semantically proper; I know that's a huge problem in itself.)